# how to give read and write access in app.config file windows application

Tags: c#-4.0

In my windows application i have attached database, i created setup file, when i run the application after installing setup file, its works nice, but the data is not saving to database, its shows the error, access denied. so please tell me how to give read and write access to the database in app.config file.

```
 <add name="StockEntities" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Stock.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: U didn't use any user to connect to Database ???

Comment: @Bui Akinori, No...i need the correct format, plz provide me